# Babel not transpile files from parent dir

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, es6-modules

How can I tell babel to transpile files that are not in current (root) directory?

Here is my project structure:

```
|-project
    |build  
        |-node_modules
            -.babel.rc
            -package.json
    |src
    |test
```

My source files are in "src", my test files are in "test".

I want to run mocha test from my package json script. I use babel to transpile my src files (ES6, React) on the fly.

Here is my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register '../test/**/*Test.js'"
}
```

and .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

But when I run yarn test, I get error message like this:

```
/src/App.spec.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I'v tried milion config combination, but nothing works, I don't want to have package.json and babel config files in the project root (that works) and I couldn't figure it out how to tell babel what to transpile, without changing project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to this solution:

package.json:

```
"test": "NODE_PATH=$PWD/node_modules:$PWD/../src/ mocha --require babelRegister.js ../test/**/*.spec.js"
```

babelRegister.js:

```
require('@babel/register')({
    extends: './.babelrc',
    ignore:  [/node_modules/],
});
```

Both "extends" and "ignore" must be set, otherwise it's not working. Looks hackish but I didn't find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you posted, it seems your babel configuration cannot process jsx syntax. You can resolve this by installing `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` plugin.

And configuring it like so:

`.babelrc`

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t help, It breaks on import, before any jsx. The problem is that my source file is not in the same directory. When i put it in the same folder it works, buy my project have different structure, and i want to find solution with this file structure.